# Why does my texture look fine in preview but not when rendered?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

In the end, the texture is supposed to look bumpy like this.
[image: correct material and texture]

It looks just like that in the preview, but not when rendered. I've tried about everything I could think of, short of restarting the entire project from scratch. I've made about three textures the same way, but none of them seem to work. I even tried moving the object to another project in case it was something with the file. I am a complete noob and know almost nothing about this program. Here is how it looks like now, if that's be any help. [image: how_it_looks_like]

Comment: Could you post your .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend or, at the very least, take a screenshot that shows the complete settings for the texture.

Comment: Thank you for you help! It works fine now. Sorry about not posting the settings, I didn't even know there was a site to upload blend files at! Likely irrelevant at this point, but here is how the settings looked like before using your advice. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a normal map texture only. You need 2 textures: the bump map, and the diffuse. The following image show the steps for setting up the two textures:
[image: diffuse texture settings]
[image: normal map texture settings]

Comment: I believe you're overcomplicating it. I set it up with only one texture and no UV. Here's the .blend http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33294. UV unwrapping may be necessary for more precise control of where the bumps end up, but since the OP clearly has distorted noise as his/her bumpmap texture, precise control doesn't seen to be a requirement.

Comment: ok , ill take  a look

Comment: was it ment to look like this? http://prntscr.com/5fr2m5

Comment: Yes, that's it. And the size of the bumps can be readily adjusted by tweaking the settings for the distorted noise. By increasing the distorsion value, I got this: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/24yqlw4/8. And by changing Nabla, Noise distorsion and Basis, it's perfectly possible to tweak the looks quite a lot.